# Kendo Grid Angular custom sort by one field

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I need to add sorting by one field by absolute value of the value. 
This is my component:

```
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData | async"
            [filterable]="true"
            [pageSize]="10"
            [pageable]="true"
            [sortable]="true"
            [height]="410">
  <kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let col of columns"
                     [field]="col.field"
                     [title]="col.title"
                     [filterable]="col.filter"
                     [filter]="col.type"
                     [format]="col.format"
                     [sortable]="col.sortable"


  ></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

This is my component class:

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

  gridData: any;

  columns = [
    { filter: true,  title: 'Name', field: 'name', type: 'text' },
    { filter: true,  title: 'Date', field: 'date', type: 'date', format: '{0:MM/dd/yyyy}' },
    { filter: true,  title: 'Amount', field: 'amount', type: 'numeric' , sortable: true},
    { filter: true,  title: 'Currency', field: 'currency'}
  ];

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.preloadData();
  }

  private preloadData() {
    this.gridData = this.dataService.getData();
  }
}
```

I tried to add instead sortable:true this:

```
sortable: {compare: function(a,b) { return Math.abs(a) > Math.abs(b)} }
```

However it tells me that this function expects boolean to be returned. So, is there a way how to implement my own comparator?

Comment: Are all the data is returned from the server? Or a pagination is implemented on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a `sortChange` event handler and `sort` model:

```
[sort]="sort"
(sortChange)="sortChange($event)"
```

And handle it on the TS:

```
public sortChange(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
  this.sort = sort;
  // Custom sort if it the field is amount and there is a direction
  if (sort[0].field === "amount" && sort[0].dir) {
    this.gridData.data = this.data.sort((a, b) =>
      this.amountSortFunction(a, b, sort[0].dir)
    );
  // If it is amount field but with no direction, then do the default sorting on name
  } else if (sort[0].field === "amount") {
    this.gridData.data = orderBy(this.data, [{ field: "name", dir: "asc" }]);
  // Other fields sorting
  } else {
    this.gridData.data = orderBy(this.data, sort);
  }
}

private amountSortFunction(a, b, direction) {
  if (direction === "asc") {
    return Math.abs(a.amount) - Math.abs(b.amount);
  }
  return Math.abs(b.amount) - Math.abs(a.amount);
}
```

You can check a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sorting-kendoui-rzsrdd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Please note that if there is a pagination from the server side, then the sorting / filtering won't work as expected, as it will be only for the same page you have and not for all data. The solution for this to implement the filtration and sorting on the server side. So if you want to sort / filter, you will send a request to the server asking him to do it, then the response will be sorted / filtered, and you will need to replace the data you have with the sorted / filtered one.

Comment: Awesome! Thank You! Can not rate the answer because of my low reputation :(

Comment: Actually because of using [kendoGridBinding]="gridData | async" it does not do sorting using sortChange function. Looks like Kendo Grid holds values and sort it in memory by its rules. It is not possible to resort data object of Observable and set it to grid and tell it to refresh